# Obtener ID de un formulario a otro Laravel

Tags: laravel

Les comento, estoy haciendo el envío de 2 formularios de forma separada, un formulario pertenece al curso, el cual se coloca el nombre, cuántos alumnos, fecha inicio y fin, después, se abre un segundo modal el cual da la opción de insertar las clases, qué día van a ser, la hora, el profesor, etc.
el tema es que cada clase de horario debe ir con el id_curso que estoy insertando a la misma vez, pero no sé cómo puedo recibir el id_curso que estoy insertando a la vez con el horario, estos son mis códigos:

---

> CABE DESTACAR QUE ESTAS INSERCIONES ESTÁN EN EL MISMO CONTROLLER YA
>   QUE VAN DE LA MANO

---

**INSERCION DEL CURSO**

```js
public
function store(Request $request)

{

  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    //curso
    'cod_curso' => 'required',
    'fecha_inicio' => 'required',
    'fecha_termino' => 'required',
    'cant_max_alumnos' => 'required',
    'id_licencia' => 'required',
    'id_estado' => 'required',

  ]);

  if ($validator->passes()) {

    $curso = CursoModel::updateOrCreate(['id_curso' => $request-> id_curso], [
      //campo de la tabla -> campo del input name
      'cod_curso' => $request->codigo_curso,
      'cant_max_alumnos' => $request->cant_alumnos,
      'id_licencia' => $request->id_licencia,
      'fecha_inicio' => $request->curso_start_date,
      'fecha_termino' => $request->curso_end_date
    ]);



    
    if (empty($request->filled('id_curso'))) {

      $message = array(
        'message' => 'Curso ha sido agregado con exito',
        'type' => 'success'
      );
    } else {
      $message = array(
        'message' => 'Sus cambios han sido guardados con exito',
        'type' => 'success'
      );
    }


    return redirect()->back()->with($message);
  } else {

    $message = array(
      'message' => 'Los datos han sido mal ingresados',
      'type' => 'error'
    );
    return redirect()->back()->with($message);
  }


}
```

**INSERCIÓN DEL HORARIO**

```js
   public function storeHorario(Request $request)
   {

    $id_curso = $request->id_curso; 
    $clase = $request->clase;
    $fecha_clase = $request->fecha_clase;
    $hora_clase = $request->hora_clase;
    $duracion_clase = $request->duracion_clase;
    $profesor = $request->profesor;


    for ($count = 0; $count<count($clase); $count++){
        $horario = array(
            'clase_nombre' => $clase[$count],
             'fecha'=>$fecha_clase[$count],
             'hora'=>$hora_clase[$count],
             'id_bloque'=>$duracion_clase[$count],
             'id_user'=>$profesor[$count],
             'id_curso' => $request->id_curso[$count]
            );
        $insertHorario[] = $horario;

    }
    // $horario->horario()->sync([$id_curso]);
    Horario::insert($insertHorario);


    $message= array(
                    'message' => 'Su horario ha sido agregado con exito',
                    'type' => 'success'
                );
    return redirect()->back()->with(['message',$message]);
   }
```

**Este es el ajax en el cual envió el json y activo el submit de alumno**

```js
$.ajax({
  url:"{{ route('alumno.horario') }}",
  type: 'POST',
  dataType:'json',
  contentType: 'json',
  data: JSON.stringify(p),
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  success : function(){
    $('#alumno-frm').submit(); // ENVIO FORMULARIO DE ALUMNO MEDIANTE SU RUTA
  },
  error: function(){
    Toast.fire({
      type: 'error',
      title: 'Ha ocurrido un problema con el registro de horario práctico'
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Yo te recomendaría que primero te encargues de guardar todas las dependencias que tiene el horario, y luego puedes crear tantos registros de horarios como desees, es lo más práctico que veo. Si estas necesitando cargar en la misma pantalla ambas entidades, podrías utilizar un proceso ajax para cargar el curso y otro ajax para cargar el horario, utilizando los métodos que ya tienes escritos.

Comment: Si, estaba pensando lo mismo :( aunque no era la idea, pero creo que seria lo mas practico, gracias por la recomendación amigo

Comment: podrias hacerlo utilizando ajax asi hacer la primera consulta y la segunda le colocas el id obtenido

Comment: ya estoy usando ajax para enviar los datos del formulario al controller :c, de ser posible lo que me comentas como tendría que ser? @steven

Comment: Version de laravel? Estás utilizando alguna libreria javascript?

Comment: no ninguna libreria y la version de laravel es la 5.8

Comment: Estás usando jquery para el ajax? o es lo que piensas usar?

Comment: edite la pregunta y coloque el ajax, con el ajax capturo los datos de los forms y los envio mediante json al controller

Comment: @MatiasMuñoz Lo que necesitas es agregar en el ajax crear un input hidden con el value del id que estas obteniendo del controlador

Comment: ¿Puedes colocar ambos formularios en tu pregunta?, porfavor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Primero

- tienes que preparar el controlador para que reciba peticiones vía ajax y te responda un json y no una vista

en tu `store`, vas a cambiar `return redirect()->back()->with($message);` por:

```
if($request->ajax()){
  return response()->json([
    'curso_id' => $curso->id
  ]);         
}else{
  return redirect()->back()->with($message);
}
```

> - el **PROBLEMA** que radica en que `$curso->id` solo va a estar disponible cuando se cree el curso, pero cuando se haga update, no. Así que asegúrate de colocar el id del curso, incluso cuando hagas update.
> - Si quieres puedes aplicar esta misma lógica para cuando el validador se activa. ya que por ajax no va a mostrar el mensaje.

#### Segundo

En este ejemplo, lo ilustré con 2 formularios ya tu lo acomodas.

El mas importante es el segundo formulario que tiene un `input` de tipo `hidden` para colocar el id cuando el ajax se corra.

```js
var cursoForm = $('#curso-form').serialize()

$.ajax({
 url: '/url-here'
 method: 'post'
 data: cursoForm,
 success(response){
  
   $('#curso_id').val( response.curso_id )
   
   // Aquí debería ir el código que abra el otro modal
   
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- formulario del curso -->
<form id="curso-form">
  <input name="name" value="Curzo de zapatos"/>
</form>

<!-- formulario del los horarios -->
<form id="horario-form">
  <input type="hidden" name="curso_id" id="curso_id"/>
</form>
```

Espero te sirva, cualquier cosa ahi están los comentarios para las dudas

Answer (score 0):

Podrias utilizar variables de sesión para esto, guardando el id del curso guardado y luego llamando la variable de sesión al momento de querer insertarlo en los registros de horario. Algo así:

```
session::put('id_curso',NULL);
session::put('id_curso',$curso);
```

Esto lo colocarías justo después de ingresar el curso. Y luego llamarías la variable así:

```
$id_curso=session::get('id_curso');
```

Comment: como se usaría esta función ya que no la entiendo, estuve investigando pero no lo entiendo